# if condition and looping in groovy template engine

Tags: groovy

I am creating a template in groovy xml template engine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <com xmlns:gsp='http://groovy.codehaus.org/2005/gsp'>
    <rawData><gsp:expression>object1.getDate()</gsp:expression></rawData>
    </com>
```

I want to create some tag on the basis of condition. Is it possible to write if else condition and loop in groovy template engine?

Comment: Use <gsp:scriptlet> tag to write a groovy code

Comment: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/1016

Comment: @Daggett Can you please tell, how to use if-else statement also.